# Searching for data from model in CakePHP

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I am working on my first project experimenting with CakePHP.  Basically I have a site where I want users to be able to search through different workouts stored in a MySQL database.

When users enter a search term, I want to simply return any workouts whose names contain the search term.  On top of that, I want them to be able to apply filters to narrow down the search to specific muscle groups.

The filters are passed to the search action through a querystring, and the search term is passed using the post method.

First off, here are the two models I care about right now:

```
class Workout extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Workout';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'MuscleGroup' =>
            array(
                'className'              => 'MuscleGroup',
                'joinTable'              => 'workouts_muscle_groups',
                'foreignKey'             => 'workout_id',
                'associationForeignKey'  => 'muscle_group_id',
                'unique'                 => true,
                'conditions'             => '',
                'fields'                 => '',
                'order'                  => '',
                'limit'                  => '',
                'offset'                 => '',
                'finderQuery'            => '',
                'deleteQuery'            => '',
                'insertQuery'            => ''
            )
    );
}


class MuscleGroup extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'MuscleGroup';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Workout' =>
            array(
                'className'              => 'Workout',
                'joinTable'              => 'workouts_muscle_groups',
                'foreignKey'             => 'muscle_group_id',
                'associationForeignKey'  => 'workout_id',
                'unique'                 => true,
                'conditions'             => '',
                'fields'                 => '',
                'order'                  => '',
                'limit'                  => '',
                'offset'                 => '',
                'finderQuery'            => '',
                'deleteQuery'            => '',
                'insertQuery'            => ''
            )
    );
}
```

Now below is the search action in my WorkoutsController:

```
function search() {
    $hasFilters = false;
    $filters = array(
        "abs" => false, 
        "back" => false, 
        "biceps" => false, 
        "chest" => false, 
        "forearms" => false, 
        "legs" => false, 
        "shoulders" => false, 
        "triceps" => false
    );

    if(isset($this->params['url']['abs']))
        if($this->params['url']['abs'] == "1")
            $filters['abs'] = $hasFilters = true;
    if(isset($this->params['url']['back']))
        if($this->params['url']['back'] == "1")
            $filters['back'] = $hasFilters = true;
    if(isset($this->params['url']['biceps']))
        if($this->params['url']['biceps'] == "1")
            $filters['biceps'] = $hasFilters = true;
    if(isset($this->params['url']['chest']))
        if($this->params['url']['chest'] == "1")
            $filters['chest'] = $hasFilters = true;
    if(isset($this->params['url']['forearms']))
        if($this->params['url']['forearms'] == "1")
            $filters['forearms'] = $hasFilters = true;
    if(isset($this->params['url']['legs']))
        if($this->params['url']['legs'] == "1")
            $filters['legs'] = $hasFilters = true;
    if(isset($this->params['url']['shoulders']))
        if($this->params['url']['shoulders'] == "1")
            $filters['shoulders'] = $hasFilters = true;
    if(isset($this->params['url']['triceps']))
        if($this->params['url']['triceps'] == "1")
            $filters['triceps'] = $hasFilters = true;


    $query = $this->request->data['search'];

    //insert code here to actually perform the search!     

}
```

I was really hoping for an easy way to do this but I have been poking around the documentation all night and can't seem to find any relevant examples.  In EntityFramework I could simply say something like:

```
List<Workout> results = context.Workouts.Where(w => w.Name.Contains(searchTerm) && w.MuscleGroups.Any(g => g.Id == mg_id)).ToList();
```

Note: no idea if that C# syntax is anywhere near correct, but the ease of accessing data from the model was somewhere close to that from what I remember.

How can I get the equivalent of that from CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MuscleGroup IDs for filtering, instead of their names. I guess the user will select them from a list, anyway.

Then, the `find()` should work like this:

```
$this->Workout->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Workout.name LIKE' => '%'.$searchTerm.'%',
            // List of included MuscleGroups:
            'MuscleGroup.id' => array(1, 5, 9, 17)  
        )   
    )   
);
```

Note that you need to take care that the related MuscleGroup is included in the Workout query, either by setting `$this->Workout->recursive = 1` or (recommended) by using the more flexible ContainableBehavior.

Comment: Your code works great for search terms, and I did go and change all the filters to go by id instead of name.  However, it throws an error when I use the 'MuscleGroup.id' => array(1,3) part.  I'm guessing this has to do with the ContainableBehavior thing?  I guess I will look into that...